# xgboost error predictions R

Tags: r, xgboost, predict, kaggle

I am using xgboost to predict airbnb destinations (similar to the Kaggle competition but for a class project). However when running the prediction command I receive this error message:

Error in predict.xgb.Booster(bst, dval) : 
  Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!

How can I fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
    setwd("~/Documents/Big Data/Datasets-20180304")
airbnb <- read.csv("airbnb_train.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
airbnb_test <- read.csv("airbnb_test.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
airbnb <- na.omit(airbnb)
airbnb_test <- na.omit(airbnb_test)
airbnb$country_destination <- as.factor(airbnb$country_destination)

airbnb$country_destination[airbnb$country_destination==0] <- NA
airbnb$country_destination <- recode(airbnb$country_destination, "c('1') = '0'; c('2') = '1'")
airbnb <- na.omit(airbnb)
airbnb_test <- na.omit(airbnb_test)

set.seed(1234)
train_index <- sample(1:nrow(airbnb),size = 0.7*nrow(airbnb),replace = F)
train <- airbnb[train_index,]
validation <- airbnb[-train_index,]

options(na.action='na.pass')
new_tr = sparse.model.matrix(country_destination~.-1,data = train, with = F)
train_label <- train$country_destination
train_label <- as.numeric(train_label)-1
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_tr, label=train_label)


new_val = sparse.model.matrix(country_destination~.-1,data = validation, with = F)
val_label <- validation$country_destination
val_label <- as.numeric(val_label)-1
dval <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_val, label=val_label)

#default parameters
params <- list(
  booster = "gbtree",
  objective = "binary:logistic",
  eta=0.3,
  gamma=0,
  max_depth=6,
  min_child_weight=1,
  subsample=1,
  colsample_bytree=1
)

bst <- xgboost(data = dtrain, label = train_label, max_depth = 2, eta = 1, nthread = 2, nrounds = 8, objective = "binary:logistic")

xgbpred <- predict(bst,dval)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I ensure that both 'bst' and 'dval' have the same feature_names?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this page (https://rdrr.io/cran/xgboost/src/R/xgb.Booster.R), you will see that some R users are likely to get the following error message: "Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!".

Here is the code from this page related to the error message:

```
predict.xgb.Booster <- function(object, newdata, missing = NA, outputmargin = FALSE, ntreelimit = NULL,predleaf = FALSE, predcontrib = FALSE, approxcontrib = FALSE, predinteraction = FALSE,reshape = FALSE, ...)

object <- xgb.Booster.complete(object, saveraw = FALSE)
      if (!inherits(newdata, "xgb.DMatrix"))
        newdata <- xgb.DMatrix(newdata, missing = missing)
      if (!is.null(object[["feature_names"]]) &&
          !is.null(colnames(newdata)) &&
          !identical(object[["feature_names"]], colnames(newdata)))
        stop("Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!")
```

`identical(object[["feature_names"]], colnames(newdata))` => If the column names of `object` (i.e. your model based on your training set) are not identical to the column names of `newdata` (i.e. your test set), you will get the error message.

For more details:

```
train_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(training %>% select(-target)), label = training$target, missing = NaN)
object <- xgb.train(data=train_matrix, params=..., nthread=2, nrounds=..., prediction = T)
newdata <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(test %>% select(-target)), missing = NaN)
```

While setting by yourself `object` and `newdata` with your data thanks to the code above, you can probably fix this issue by looking at the differences between `object[["feature_names"]]` and `colnames(newdata)`. Probably some columns that don't appear in the same order or something.

Comment: Compiling @quiotan and @Skotten89 solutions leads to: `predict(model, as.matrix(data %>% dplyr::select(model$feature_names)))`

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what are your `names(bst)` and `names(dval)`?
After you applying boosting model:

```
bst <- xgboost(data = dtrain, label = train_label, max_depth = 2, eta = 1, nthread = 2, nrounds = 8, objective = "binary:logistic")
```

As a workaround you could simply do:

```
names(bst) <- names(dval)
```

and then try your prediction:

```
xgbpred <- predict(bst,dval)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with similar problem and this worked for me.

Try removing predicting variable, i.e. train$country_destination in your case, from 'dtrain' and 'dtest' (even if you have blank values filled in there). Try training the model again after making that change.

Answer (score 0):

Following guiotan answers, using

`library(dplyr)`

You should be able to write:

`xgbpred <- predict(bst, dval %>% select(bst$feature_names))`

If you trained xgboost using `caret`, a solution would be to write the following.

`xgbpred <- predict(bst, dval %>% select(bst$finalModel$feature_names))`

At least this worked for me.